# Redmine with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite, redmine

I used the installation guide [here](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/installing-redmine-on-windows-in-production/) to install Redmine to our Windows production server using IIS 7.  The installation was smooth and required almost no input from me --- I just hit "go" and it did everything.

However, our production server already has SQL Server 2008 R2.  In setting Redmine up, it appears to have automatically installed and set up the required database in a separate engine.  I'd like to migrate this to our SQL Server 2008 R2, just to centralize everything into one engine, so we have one less thing to keep tabs on.

According to that installation guide, Redmine supports multiple database engines.  But I don't understand the instructions given in the "Custom Database" section.  For one, it says to go the config folder of the Redmine application and choose the file that corresponds to my desired database engine and rename it to database.yml.

Here's what I have in my Redmine config folder:

```
[folder] environments
[folder] initializers
[folder] locales
additional_environment.rb.example
application.rb
boot.rb
configuration.yml.example
database.yml
database.yml.example
environment.rb
preinitializer.rb
routes.rb
settings.yml
```

So first of all, I don't see any kind of "database.yml.mssql" file like I was hoping for.  I went ahead and opened database.yml in Notepad just to see what I'm working with, and this is the contents of that file:

```
production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
  encoding: utf8

development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
  encoding: utf8
```

I have absolutely zero experience with databases other than Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.  My first question is, where in the world did mysql and sqlite3 get installed?  I can't find any trace of them, and I have no idea how to "see" the databases, even through command line.

Of interest is a folder called "db" inside the Redmine application folder.  This folder contains:

```
[folder] migrate
schema.rb
test.sqlite3
```

These files are almost surely related, but I'm not seeing how everything ties together.  The migrate folder contains a bunch of .rb files like 001_setup.rb and 105_build_projects_tree.rb.

I did search Google for like "redmine sql server", and the problem with the results is that in some cases a thread was begun with the same question and never followed up on, OR, the post/thread is years old and possibly no long reliable.

Right now Redmine appears to be working.  I can create users, log in, and so on.  But it's a huge blackbox.  If migration to SQL Server 2008 R2 is not feasible and I'm stuck using whatever the default is, I want to know where the database that Redmine is using is, and how I can view the tables, etc.

**The bottom line question: how can I modify Redmine to use SQL Server 2008 R2?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience using Redmine with MSSQL, so I can't answer your main question.  But I can offer some info on two of your sub-questions:

First, I'm pretty sure that the "development" db (the mysql one) doesn't exist.  The database.yml always seems to include that (I guess as an example of how to have one Redmine instance that has both a test and prod database), but the installation only creates the production database.

You also asked about how to see the database, if you're stuck using the sqlite db for now.  There is a command-line program at http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html that ought to enable you to query and modify the db.